# Google Web Toolkit: Ever used for making games?

Tags: web

I've recently come across GWT (Google Web Toolkit) and have been amazed by it. I was wondering if anyone has ever put it to use making a video game? And if they did, what their experience was, whether it was worth it and whether the game was any good.

Comment: Electronic Arts used GWT to port a game to a web version in "less than 48 hours": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0WDNisAMeY#t=11m30s

Comment: impressive. Very impressive

Comment: @amitp You should turn that comment into an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in a talk from this year's Google I/O about [using GWT, WebGL, and App Engine to build game tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNmoEOpGJdk). I would never have imagined that could be a really killer combination but was really surprised at how awesome it looked.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the EA game mentioned in amitp's comment, Rovio used GWT to port ["Angry Birds"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj) to the web (with a bit of Flash to work around HTML5's sad audio situation).

There was a dzone article about it not to long ago: ["Web Gaming Technologies: Angry Birds' Cross-compiled Java Versus Native JavaScript"](http://css.dzone.com/articles/web-gaming-technologies-angry).